# Sublime Text 3 - Buscar todas las llaves que no tienen un espacio antes

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

Quiero que todos mis bloques de CSS tengan un espacio antes de la llave abierta. Muchas veces se les olvida a mis amigos, por lo que me toca corregir de vez en cuando.

Quisiera una expresión regular que me localice todas las llaves que no tienen un espacio al principio, por ejemplo:

```
.class1{ // Match 1
  color: red;

  ul{ // Match 2
    list-style-type: none;

    li{ // Match 3
      height: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

Luego de localizarlas, insertar el espacio para que quede así:

```
.class1 {
  color: red;

  ul {
    list-style-type: none;

    li {
      height: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no tengo sublime text, pero estoy seguroq ue esta expresión regular te ayudará:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)({)
```

Para el segundo parámetro del remplazo usa:

```
$1 $2
```

### Explicación

Todo lo que esté entre paréntesis es un grupo, por ello se les conoce como **grupo de captura** a cada uno de ellos, en nuestro caso hay dos.
Se numeran de izquierda a derecha, de la siguiente manera

```
     1         2
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)({)
```

El caracter es un **cuantificador**  `+` significa uno o más del elemento anterior.
Aquello entre corchetes indica un único caracter de entre las opciones, pero para evitarnos escribir todos los caracteres usamos **rangos**, los rangos son caracteres consecutivos representados de la forma

```
a-b
```

donde el valor de `a` siempre debe ser menor que `b` para incluir a todos los elementos entre `a` y `b`, incluyendo `a` y `b`.
Por lo anterior `[a-zA-Z0-9]` significa letras ASCII en mayúsculas y minúsculas además de los números naturales.

Es importante notar que el segundo parámetro lleva un espacio entre el primer `$1` y segundo grupo de captura `$2`.

Comment: Si por alguna ra´zon no te reconoce la notación `$numerodegrupo` puedes intentar también con `\numerodegrupo` que es la sintaxis natural de python

Comment: Buenísimo. La expresión regular me funcionó. Adicional, sublime text tiene un botón a un lado del cuadro de búsqueda (su símbolo es **.\***) para especificar que se está buscando con una expresión regular. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Excelente, si te sirvió , por favor [acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)